# How to solve rejection problem of my app on google play console

Tags: android, policy, device-policy-manager

We have received these policy notice from the policy team. 
They give the following reason:

"**We were unable to verify the declared functionality {Proxy calls} during app review**".

My app manifest requests the Call Log permission group (PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS).

I am not able to understand what core functionality I need to choose.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Actually There is a Permission Deceleration Form.. Apps Which Use Call Logs and SMS need to Fill Form By 30th Jan 2019.. But Now Its changed now visit This link and follow all Instruction carefully.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102

Comment: I already visit Instruction and provide them all instructions about app and also send video of my app. but problem is not solved.

Comment: ok Also Make Certificate Verification at content Rating while releasing app

Comment: no i don't make certificate verification because its already generated

Comment: You need to change again depending up on your app you need make changes of content rating also

Comment: i change content rating and provide all details and app video in policy declaration from on play store but the problem is not solve.there response is same why.